# Split column values as Header in talend

Tags: talend, data-integration

I have a input file as follows:

file1  : A
file2  : B
file3  : C
file4  : D
file5  : E
file6   : F

and i want my Target file to look like this:

file1 | file2 | file3 | file4 | file5 | file6

A    | B     | C     | D    | E    | F

Trying to make the column values as header in the target file. is it possible with tmap, if so someone post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the tPivotToColumnsDelimited documentary [click here](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/13.43+tPivotToColumnsDelimited)

Comment: Hi Mulin i have tried using pivot component but it is asking for group by which doesnt make sense in my example.